# Trying to return function to every view from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have the following function in my ProjectsController
EDIT: i want to render this in _Layout.html

```
    ' Show Count of projects
    Function Menu() As PartialViewResult
        Dim count = 15
        Return PartialView(count)
    End Function
```

Now ive tried using @html.renderpartial("Menu", "Projects") but this did nothing ive also tried things like returning it as a actionresult and using html.renderaction or html.action but both didnt work

Please help me out

Comment: Do you get an error, or does the partial view HTML not appear on the page?

Comment: it doesnt return anything and i get a child handler system error

Comment: Use `@Html.Action("Menu", "Projects")` to call the server method and render the partial view it returns (or `@{ Html.RenderAction("Menu", , "Projects"); }`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct to use `ActionResult` as the return type of the method.

When using Html.RenderAction you need to do it like this:

`@{ Html.RenderAction("About"); }`

If I recall, you need to wrap the call around `@{}` becasue RenderAction writes it output to the Http response stream, not as a return value of the function. That means calling this:

`@Html.RenderAction("About")`

Will result is nothing being outputted onto the page.